# OpenERP auto reply email

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, erp

I have installed two version of OpenERP. One on my local machine and another one on remote machine. I tried today configure auto reply email on incoming email for my customers.

So, in **Settings --> Configuration --> Incoming Mail Servers** for *Actions to Perform on Incoming Mails* i set:

- **Create a New Record** : crm.lead
- **Server Action** : auto_reply

Of course, I created **auto_reply** server action and set following fields:

- **Action Name** : auto_reply
- **Object** : crm.lead
- **Action Type** : Email
- **Sequence** : 5
- **Condition** : True
- **Email Address** : object.email_from
- **Subject** : blah blah blah
- **Message** : blah blah blah

On my local machine this working perfectly. I'm always getting auto reply email. But, on remote machine auto reply don't working for this case, but working correctly when I put static email (e.g. example@gmail.com) in *Email Address* field instead of *object.email_from*.

I took a look on log file on remote machine, and saw following error:

```
2012-11-16 14:46:23,288 7968 ERROR ? fetchmail: Failed to fetch mail from imap server Google server
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/openerp/addons/fetchmail/fetchmail.py", line 195, in fetch_mail
    action_pool.run(cr, uid, [server.action_id.id], {'active_id': res_id, 'active_ids':[res_id]})
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_actions.py", line 685, in run
    res_email = ir_mail_server.send_email(cr, uid, msg)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_mail_server.py", line 382, in send_email
    assert smtp_to_list, "At least one valid recipient address should be specified for outgoing emails (To/Cc/Bcc)"
AssertionError: At least one valid recipient address should be specified for outgoing emails (To/Cc/Bcc)
```

OpenERP version on local machine: OpenERP Server 6.1-20121001-232851

OpenERP version on remote machine: OpenERP Server 6.1-1

Because, different versions on local and remote machine I saw that some files are different, for example *ir_mail_server.py*

Is this a bug? Can someone point me, how to solve a problem. I don't have full access on remote machine, so I can't install version as version on my local machine. But, I can change some lines of source code. It's not a problem.

What if I overwrite *base* module with latest release of OpenERP, and run:

```
openerp-server -d mydb -u base
```

Because, I already installed many modules and have many useful data, are there some consequences for this action? Thank you.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

From the error message I'm guessing that `object.email_from` might be empty. I would suggest you to start the server with the `--debug` option, and the  `(pdb)` prompt inspect the the variables with commands such as

```
pp msg
```

(tip: type `h` to get help on the commands available).

Answer (score 0):

However, I get access to remote machine and update OpenERP server. Auto reply with configuration above now working perfectly.

My new version: `OpenERP Server 6.1-20121116-003252`